# The cone over a projective variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I'm trying to prove that $I(C(Y))=I(Y)$, where $C(Y)=\pi^{-1}(Y)\cup \{(0,\ldots,0)\}$ the cone over $Y$ and $\pi:\mathbb A^{n+1}-\{0,\ldots,0\}\to \mathbb P^n$ the projection which sends the point with affine coordinates $(a_0,\ldots,a_n)$ to the point with homogeneous coordinates $(a_0,\ldots,a_n)$.

**My attempt of solution**

$I(C(Y))=I\bigg(\pi^{-1}(Y)\cup\{(0,\ldots,0)\}\bigg)=I\bigg(\pi^{-1}(Y)\bigg)\cap I\bigg(\{(0,\ldots,0)\}\bigg)=?$

The last term should be equal to $I(Y)$, but I don't know why.

I really need help.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: This is no going to work. Why don; t you try, instead, to think about what sort of polynomials vanish on $C(Y)$?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez the polynomials which vanish on $C(Y)$ are the same which vanish on I(Y) and on (0,...,0). I can't go further.

Answer (score 2):

Let $S=\Bbbk[x_0,\ldots,x_n]$. Note that a homogeneous polynomial vanishes on $\pi^{-1}(Y)$ if and only if it "vanishes" on $Y$, simply by the definition of "vanshing" for homogeneous polynomials on sets of projective coordinates. Thus, $I(C(Y))$ contains $I(Y)$ and it is contained in $S_+$. Let us show that $I(C(Y))\subseteq I(Y)$. Let $f\in I(C(Y))$. Then, $f=\sum_{d=0}^{r} f_d$ with all the $f_d$ homogeneous of degree $d$. Let $a\in C(Y)$, then $t a\in C(Y)$ for any $t\in\Bbbk^\times$. Hence,
$$0 = \sum_{d=0}^r f_d(t a) = \sum_{d=0}^r f_d(a) t^d $$
Assuming that your field is infinite, this means that the polynomial $\sum_{d=0}^r f_d(a)\cdot T^d\in \Bbbk[T]$ has too many zeros to not be the zero polynomial. In other words, $f_d(a)=0$ for all $d$, so $f_d\in I(C(Y))$. Hence, $f$ is a sum of elements of $I(Y)$, therefore $I(C(Y))\subseteq I(Y)$.

Note that you get $(0,\ldots,0)$ for free because homogeneous polynomials vanish at the origin anyway.

Comment: Can I say that $I\bigg(\pi^{-1}(Y)\bigg)\cap I\bigg(\{(0,\ldots,0)\}\bigg)=I(Y)$ because I(0,...,0) is every homogeneous polynomials? Thank you very much

Comment: @user42912: That's not *quite* correct, because $I(\mathbf 0)=(x_0,\ldots,x_n)$ is a homogeneous ideal, but of course it contains polynomials that are not homogeneous. You simply have $I(\pi^{-1}(Y))=I(\pi^{-1}(Y)\cup\{ \mathbf 0 \})=I(Y)$.

Comment: Do you mean to say, "let $a\in Y$, so $ta\in C(Y)$...$f_d\in I(Y)$"?

Comment: shouldn't the polynomial start at d = 0?

Comment: Thx @Auburn, that was a typo.

Comment: @JeskoHüttenhain I can't see any difference between $S_+$ and $(x_0 ,\dots ,x_n)$ - both seem to be the ideal of polynomials without constant coefficients. Do they indeed coincide?

Comment: @Arrow yes they are. Just different notation. It is also sometimes called the _irrelevant ideal_.

Comment: @JeskoHüttenhain great, then I'm not going crazy :)

Comment: @Arrow it's a definite occupational hazard, but I think you're fine. =)

Comment: @JeskoHüttenhain I have another quick question. Let $U_i$ be the usual open cover of $\mathbb P^n$ and let $\pi:\mathbb A^{n+1}\setminus\left\{ 0 \right\}\twoheadrightarrow \mathbb P^n$ the quotient map. Suppose we apriori topologize $\mathbb P^n$ w.r.t the atlas given by the $U_i$. How can I see $\pi$ is continuous? I don't see why $\pi|_{\pi^{-1}U_i}$ is continuous, but I think that should be the proof.

Comment: @Arrow I don't think the answer properly fits in a comment, essentially one would reiterate the argument that regular maps are continuous, which boils down to the fact that they are locally given by polynomials.

Answer (score 0):

I think it follows straight from the definitions:
$$I_p(V)=\{F:F(\lambda x)=0\forall[x]\in V\forall\lambda\neq 0\}$$ 
$$C(V)=\{(x):[x]\in V\}\cup\{0\}=\{(\lambda x):[x]\in V,\lambda\in\mathbb{k}\}$$
$$I_a(C(V))=\{F:F(\lambda x)=0\forall [x]\in V\forall\lambda\in\mathbb{k}\}$$
Only difference is the case $\lambda=0$. But notice how $I_p(V)$ is always homogeneous, which means the homogeneous parts of each $F\in I_p(V)$ must be in the ring too. This includes the constant terms. So the constant terms must be zero. Consequently, these polynomials vanish at $0$ as well.
Of course, the above is true provided the field is infinite.